# Angular form with nested arrays error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, formbuilder, formarray

I have a problem with the form in which the arrays are nested.
In the console I saw this error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

This is related to FormBuild and FormArray with FormArray inside

Code snippet:

```
export class TestPreviewDialogComponent implements OnInit {
    testModule: TestModule;
    testModuleForm: FormGroup;
    levels: LanguageLevel[] = [];

    constructor(
        @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public test: TestModule,
        public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<TestPreviewDialogComponent>,
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        private commonService: CommonService
    ) {
        this.testModule = test;

        this.testModuleForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            moduleName: '',
            moduleLevelCode: '',
            moduleDescription: '',
            questions: this.formBuilder.array([]),
        });
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getLevels();

        this.setTestModuleForm();

        setTimeout(() => {
            this.testModuleForm.disable();
        }, 1000);
    }

    // Questions
    private get questions(): FormArray {
        return this.testModuleForm.get('questions') as FormArray;
    }

    // PRIVATE
    private getLevels() {
        this.commonService.getLanguageLevels().subscribe({
            next: (value) => {
                this.levels = value;
            },
            error: (err) => {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    }

    private setTestModuleForm() {
        this.testModuleForm.controls['moduleName'].setValue(this.testModule.name);
        this.testModuleForm.controls['moduleLevelCode'].setValue(this.testModule.level);
        this.testModuleForm.controls['moduleDescription'].setValue(this.testModule.description);
        this.testModuleForm.controls['questions'].setValue(this.setQuestions());  // Console points this place in code
    }

    setQuestions() {
        this.testModule.questions.forEach((x: Question) => {
            this.questions.push(
                this.formBuilder.group({
                    questionText: x.questionText,
                    questionExplanation: x.explanation,
                    answers: this.setAnswers(x)
                })
            );
        });
    }

    setAnswers(x: Question) {
        let arr = new FormArray([]);
        x.answers.forEach((y: Answer) => {
            arr.push(
                this.formBuilder.group({
                    answerText: y.text,
                    isCorrect: y.isCorrect
                })
            );
        });
        return arr;
    }
}
```

Full error with stack:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
> at forms.mjs:1671:18
> at forms.mjs:7018:13
> at Array.forEach ()
> at FormArray._forEachChild (forms.mjs:7017:23)
> at assertAllValuesPresent (forms.mjs:1670:13)
> at FormArray.setValue (forms.mjs:6840:9)
> at TestPreviewDialogComponent.setTestModuleForm (test-preview-dialog.component.ts:66:51)
> at TestPreviewDialogComponent.ngOnInit (test-preview-dialog.component.ts:38:14)
> at callHook (core.mjs:2498:22)
> at callHooks (core.mjs:2467:17)

I feel that the questions are not initialized when `setQuestions()` function is executed
 and that's why it says `reading '0'`. But I can't overcome it as I haven't much experience

**EDIT:**

```
<div class="container-box">

    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mat-elevation-z8"
         style="border-radius: 10px; margin-bottom: 20px; height: 60px; background-color: #3f51b5;">
        <h1 style="color: #ffffff; text-shadow: 1px 1px black; line-height: 60px;">
            {{testModule.name}} - {{testModule.level}}
        </h1>
    </div>

    <form class="row px-3 py-3 mx-auto mat-elevation-z8" style="border-radius: 10px" [formGroup]="testModuleForm">

        <div class="col-6">
            <div>
                <mat-label>Nazwa testu</mat-label>
                <mat-form-field class="w-100" appearance="fill">
                    <input formControlName="moduleName" matInput>
                </mat-form-field>
            </div>

            <div>
                <mat-label>Poziom testu</mat-label>
                <mat-form-field class="w-100" appearance="fill">
                    <mat-select formControlName="moduleLevelCode" placeholder="Poziom zaawansowania">
                        <mat-option *ngFor="let lvl of levels" [value]="lvl.shortName">
                            {{lvl.shortName}} - {{lvl.fullName}}
                        </mat-option>
                    </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-6">
            <div>
                <mat-label>Opis</mat-label>
                <mat-form-field class="w-100" appearance="fill">
                    <textarea formControlName="moduleDescription" matInput style="height: 107px; resize: none;"
                    >
                    </textarea>
                </mat-form-field>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="mt-3">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                <h3 style="font-size: 20px; font-weight:bold;">List pytań</h3>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row col-12 px-3 py-2 mx-auto" formArrayName="questions">
            <div class="question-box px-3 py-2" *ngFor="let question of testModule.questions; let questionIndex=index">

                <div [formGroupName]="questionIndex">

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-1 question-number-box">
                            <span class="question-number">{{questionIndex + 1}}.</span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-6">
                            <mat-label>Pytanie</mat-label>
                            <mat-form-field class="w-100" appearance="fill">
                                <input formControlName="questionText" matInput>
                            </mat-form-field>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-4">
                            <mat-label>Wyjaśnienie</mat-label>
                            <mat-form-field class="w-100" appearance="fill">
                                <input formControlName="questionExplanation" matInput>
                            </mat-form-field>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-1 remove-question-button-box"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row mt-3">
                        <div class="col-10 d-flex justify-content-center">
                            <h3 style="font-size: 16px; font-weight:bold;">Odpowiedzi</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-2 d-flex justify-content-center"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="answers-box row col-12 py-2" formArrayName="answers">
                        <div *ngFor="let answer of testModule.questions[questionIndex].answers; let answerIndex=index">
                            <div [formGroupName]="answerIndex">
                                <div class="row col-12">
                                    <div class="col-2"></div>
                                    <div class="col-1 answer-number-box">
                                        <span class="answer-number">{{answerIndex + 1}}.</span>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <mat-label>Odpowiedź</mat-label>
                                        <mat-form-field class="w-100" appearance="fill">
                                            <input formControlName="answerText" matInput>
                                        </mat-form-field>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-2">
                                        <mat-label>Poprawna</mat-label>
                                        <mat-form-field class="w-100" appearance="fill">
                                            <mat-select formControlName="isCorrect" placeholder="Poprawna?">
                                                <mat-option [value]="true">Tak</mat-option>
                                                <mat-option [value]="false">Nie</mat-option>
                                            </mat-select>
                                        </mat-form-field>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-1 remove-answer-button-box"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="divider"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: When do `setQuestions()` is called ? Can you also share your html ?

Comment: `setQuestions()` is being called from this line: `this.testModuleForm.controls['questions'].setValue(this.setQuestions());`


html will be provided inside the post in order to keep formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**: the problem is the line

```
this.testModuleForm.controls['questions']
           .setValue(this.setQuestions()); //<--WRONG
```

Replace by

```
//should be simply a call to the function:
this.setQuestions() //<--OK
```

See that not give value to the array "questions", else setQuestions give value to the formGroup

**note:** Always you mannage a FormArray **not** loop over a variable, loop over the formArray.controls.

```
<!---WRONG--->
<div *ngFor="let question of testModule.questions; 
                              let questionIndex=index">

<!--OK--->
<div *ngFor="let question of questions.controls; 
                let questionIndex=index">
```

See that when we have a FormArray inside a FormArray we need a function to "reach" the formArray -can not be a getter else a function we pass an "index" (the function getAnswer)

```
<!--WRONG-->
<div *ngFor="let answer of testModule.questions[questionIndex].answers;
         let answerIndex=index">

<!--OK-->
<div *ngFor="let answer of getAnswers(questionIndex).controls;
         let answerIndex=index">


getAnswer(index:number)
{
    return this.questions.at(index).get('answers') as FormArray
}
```

NOTE: I don't check your code (and don't know if you has really a FormArray), only I want to give a clue.

NOTE2:You can write in .html

```
<pre>
{{testModuleForm?.value|json}}
</pre>
```

To see if you really has the data you want -even you can comment the whole form until the data match do you want-

Comment: Changed that, but the error still remains :/

Comment: @drozdgabriel, I get the error. You write `this.testModuleForm.controls['questions'].setValue(this.setQuestions())`, really the only you need is call to the function `this.setQuestions()`. Just update answer

Answer (score 0):

Bro your code is a mess.
first of all when working with forms and update forms values individually use patchValue() instead of setValue().

```
this.testModuleForm.controls['questions'].setValue(this.setQuestions())
```

second your calling method in setValue() which is not return controls or groups that can be assigned to FormArray, that's why the array is still empty.

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

  form: FormGroup;

   constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = fb.group({
    name: [],
    address: fb.array([])
     })
    }


   addNewAddressGroup() {
     const add = this.form.get('address') as FormArray;
     add.push(this.fb.group({
     street: [],
     city: []
    }))
  }

  deleteAddressGroup(index: number) {
     const add = this.form.get('address') as FormArray;
     add.removeAt(index)
  }
```

I have added a form array example for you to do through with [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-forms-formarray-example?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: I still have a lot to learn :/ but I'm going in the right direction in small steps :D